# Как сделать поиск по блокам с атрибутом title?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Решил сделать поиск аудиозаписей. И сделал его, но он ищет точные совпадения - надо писать полное название, а мне надо что-бы написал часть названия названия и он показал предположения. Вот мои "наработки":

```
$( "input" ).change(function() {
value = $("input").val();
if (value == ""){
$(".t").show();
}
else
{
$(".t[title != '"+value+"']").hide();
}
});
```

Сам сайт, кому интересно: http://w-0rld.ru/#audios

Comment: Attribute Contains Selector [name*=”value”] - https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/

Comment: Спасибо, ответ был рядом, не думал что все так просто.

Answer (score 2):

Должно быть не `!=`, а `*=`. И не надо ставить вокруг него пробелы.